# Use Javascript document.body.className to add a body class rather than document.body.setAttribute

Tags: javascript, html, css, local-storage, addeventlistener

I'm using the function below to toggle dark mode in CSS. It uses `document.body.setAttribute` to add the attribute `data-theme="dark"` to the document body tag, and removes it when toggled again; and the function reads and/or sets localStorage `darkSwitch` to hold the dark mode state between page loads. The CSS is i.e. `[data-theme="dark"] .myselector {background-color: #000;}`.

Function:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input" id="darkSwitch" />  // Simply the button to toggle


(function() {
  var darkSwitch = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
  if (darkSwitch) {
    initTheme();
    darkSwitch.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      resetTheme();
    });
    function initTheme() {
      var darkThemeSelected =
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";
      darkSwitch.checked = darkThemeSelected;
      darkThemeSelected
        ? document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark")
        : document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
    }
    function resetTheme() {
      if (darkSwitch.checked) {
        document.body.setAttribute("data-theme", "dark");
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"); 
} else {
        document.body.removeAttribute("data-theme");
        localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch");  
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

What I want to do is modify the function to not add the data attribute `data-theme` but instead add the body class `dark` so the CSS will be i.e. `body.dark .myselector {background-color: #000;}`.

This is my attempt below to add the body class `dark` to the body tag, but of course, it doesn't work. I'm trying to use `document.body.className` and `document.body.className.replace`. How can I get this to work?

```
(function() {
  var darkSwitch = document.getElementById("darkSwitch");
  if (darkSwitch) {
    initTheme();
    darkSwitch.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
      resetTheme();
    });
    function initTheme() {
      var darkThemeSelected =
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") !== null &&
        localStorage.getItem("darkSwitch") === "dark";
      darkSwitch.checked = darkThemeSelected;
      darkThemeSelected
        ? document.body.className("dark")
        : document.body.className.replace("dark","");
    }
    function resetTheme() {
      if (darkSwitch.checked) {
        document.body.className("dark");
        localStorage.setItem("darkSwitch", "dark"); 
} else {
        document.body.className.replace("dark","");
        localStorage.removeItem("darkSwitch");  
      }
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: `className` is not a function. You're confusing it with `classList`.

Comment: Neither is classList.

Comment: I think you'd want something closer to
`? document.body.className = "dark"
   : document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("dark","");`

However, when doing a replacement, I think it's easier to use `classList.remove();`

Comment: @user1599011 Thanks, that's interesting about classList.remove; want to add an example?

Comment: Instead of `document.body.className = document.body.className.replace("dark","");`, I would use `document.body.classList.remove("dark");`

The former would also replace any partial matches. For example, `class="darkPage"` would become `class="Page"`. `className` simply treats it as a string, while `classList` handles the list aspect.

Comment: @user1599011 Thanks, that's better; the class `dark` is added and removed from the body tag. But, all classes are removed from the body tag, but they reappear after a page reload.